# Ceiling fan outlet is hot

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I'm replacing a ceiling fan.
Inside the ceiling fan outlet box, there is one white electrical cable with a Red, white, copper and black wire coming out of the electrical cable.

The ceiling fan I am replacing didn't have a light kit but the new one does, and the ceiling fan had a single light switch to turn the fan on and off.

Without moving any wires around, I simply tripped the breaker and removed the old ceiling fan wire nuts and pulled it down.

**THE PROBLEM IS THIS:**
When I turned the power on at the breaker, I tested the wires and the red wire tests that it has voltage as it should.  The problem is, much to my surprise the ceiling fan outlet box has voltage on it as well.

Visually, the white electrical cable goes through a hole in the side of the outlet box and the red wire never touches the outlet box, so how is it getting (switched) power on the outlet box if nothing is hooked up between the red wire and the outlet box?  I even temporarily removed the hold down screw/bracket to hold the electrical wire to the outlet box in case the wire was pinching through the insulation but that doesn't change anything.

**Is the outlet supposed to have electricity on it?  If not, how is it getting electricity on the outlet box if the wire isn't touching the box?  Yes, the power on the outlet box goes on and off with the switch.**

[image]

Comment: What are you checking for voltage with?  Also, does the bare wire have (switched) voltage on it as well?

Comment: How were things wired BEFORE you took the old fan down?

Comment: That bare wires **should** be ground (not neutral, or *HORRORS!* hot). Is the bare wire wrapped around a screw in the box, as it should be, and also connected to the green wire, if any, of the new fixture?? Have you checked the voltage from the box to a **known ground**?